# Maximum exponent of doubles a for which (a - 0.0001) + 0.0001 is not equal to a

Tags: floating-point, double

Suppose we are working in floating point arithmetic, with doubles, in a 64 bit machine. I would like to find the maximum exponent for which there is a `double a` with that exponent such that

```
(a - 0.0001) + 0.0001 == a
```

is **false**.

I can produce some examples: a = 5.0e-14 is one of them. In this case

```
(a - 0.0001) + 0.0001 = 5.0000002510715291e-14
```

I am working in C++, in case that is relevant. Compiler gcc-4.8.4, no optimizations.

**Background:** In a piece of code I was reviewing a variable was first shifted down by 0.0001 to do some computations, and the shifted up by 0.0001 with the goal of recovering the original value. This is not the correct way to do it. Ideally I would have just saved the original value and copied it back, instead of doing the shift back and forth. The developer has the hope that the non-associativity in floating point would not have any major effect for the rest of the code. If all such values are very close to 0.0 then that would be true in our case.

**Partial answer:** Positive numbers with exponent not greater than -5, i.e. 1.0e-5, should all be examples.

**Partial asnwer 2:** 0.00022207040003564455 is also an example and it has exponent -4.

Are there larger numbers that are also examples?

Comment: Because 0.001 isn't exactly representable as a binary floating point number, there's not going to be a simple or elegant answer to this. That's particularly the case because the way in which you've written your equation allows the compiler leeway in how/when/if it rounds intermediate values. I suggest you give more information about the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @Sneftel The problem is exactly as stated. The issue of 0.0001 not being exactly representable is not really relevant. You can assume that I wrote instead of 0.0001 the underlying binary number. It is just that that is the number they have in the code. What aspects do you think need more detail? Compiler version?

Comment: As in, what do you need to be able to do with the information? A list of all the numbers which don't satisfy your equation would be very very long, so I don't think it's what you're looking for.

Comment: @Sneftel Added some background and simplified the question.

Comment: @Sneftel Simplified the question to onlly determine the maximum exponent that such an example could have.

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot easier to characterize the situations where the result *is* correct, than the ones where it isn't.

First, all numbers between `0.00005` and `0.0002` will produce correct results; by Sterbenz's Theorem, the result of the subtraction can be exactly represented, and because the input was a FP number, so can the result of the addition.

Second, all numbers greater than `0.0001 / (eps/2)` (where `eps` is, in this case, `DBL_EPSILON` will produce correct results, since `x-0.0001`, and then the result added to `0.0001`, will simply be `x`. (Don't get too excited about that bound, it's in the billions.)

Beyond that, you have very little in the way of dependable invariants. `0.0001`rounded to a floating-point number is not a nice number: Since it is not a power of 2 nor the result of multiplying a small-ish integer by a power of 2, it's got a lot of 1s in its mantissa, mucking with your ability to reason about it. The bottom line is, floating point equality is rarely a useful thing to try, and

And even the results above assume two important things: One (in the case of the second bound), that the FP mode is round-to-nearest, and two, that all computations are performed in double-precision. The first one you can almost certainly assume unless you've gone out of your way to change it, but the C++ standard allows intermediate results in an expression to be performed at higher precision than the operands, meaning that the left hand side may have higher precision than the right hand side, and be compared at that higher precision. That allows for lots of potential nonzero mantissa bits in the left hand side that the right hand side cannot possibly measure up to.

Ultimately, there's very little you can assume about the grouping of numbers that do or do not satisfy your equation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is Sterbens's Theorem? I couldn't find a reference using Google. I looks like a useful thing to know.

Comment: Basically, that if `a` and `b` are within a factor of 2, `a-b` is exactly representable.

Comment: I've usually heard it as Sterbenz's Lemma. It is also (unattributed) Theorem 11 here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html